# Call an asmx webservice without extending user session

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, asmx, session-timeout

In my ASP.net 3.5 application I'm calling an asmx webservice that is part of the application.  Calling the webservice entends the user's session timeout, which is undesirable in this case.

How can I call a webservice on my server without extending the session timeout?  Is there a way in IIS to designate it as being outside of the session scope? (apologies if I'm using incorrect terminology)  Can I designate a directory in the ASP.net web.config file as being outside the session?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to use the session at all? Or just not extend the session time out period?

Comment: The main point is that I don't want to extend the session timeout period, but I don't need to use the session either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

You can create a new application in IIS with a root directory underneath your original application.  This is done in the IIS MMS snap-in in the properties pane of the directory you want as the new root.  Click "Create application" and you're done.  The new application inherits the parent application's web.config, seemingly, so little no configuration needs to be done.

Comment: Sometimes, this inheritance feature gives me headaches. Luckily you can wrap most of the web.config sections (like e.g. `<system.web>`) in a "location" tag like e.g. `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">` to prevent inheritance.

Comment: Thank you.  That's worth knowing :)